# Maximum size/length of regular expression in "modern" web browsers?

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the maximum size of a regular expression in modern browsers (i.e. Firefox 3+, Safari 4+, IE 7+)? Assume a simple regular expression, of, say "foo|bar|baz|woot|..."

Comment: If you have to ask, you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @Andrew Or maybe he's doing his masters thesis on esoteric browser limits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this code to test, in IE8 / firefox with firebug / Chrome.

```
var regex = "";
var maximum = 100;
var showAfter = 95;
for(i = 1; i < maximum; i++) {
    regex += "aaaaaaaaaa";
    if (i > showAfter) {
        console.log(10 * i + " chars");
        console.log(RegExp(regex));
    }
}
```

When you get a error, you found the limit.

---

**SIMPLE TEST**

```
var regex = "";
var chars = 3204161;
for(i = 0; i < chars; i++) {
    regex += "a";
}
alert(chars + " chars");
var a = RegExp(regex); // don't send to console, to be faster
```

---

**RESULTS**

In Firefox 3.6.3 (Ubuntu 32 bits) I get error when I tried a regex with <strike>9M chars (9.999.990 chars)</strike> **3.204.161** chars. With 3.204.160 it's ok.

In Chrome 5.0.3 the limit is something between 20M and 25M chars.

The error, in firefox, is:

```
script stack space quota is exhausted
```

Note: If you did some test, please comment here.

Comment: Many distributions limit stack space to 10 MB, so that's probably what you're hitting.

Comment: @Chris thanks for your comment, but the top is near 3M chars...I'm trying to get the exact number.

Comment: It sounds like for all practical purposes, RegEx size is practically unlimited. Now I'm going to go down the rabbit hole of determining the performance of absurdly large regular expressions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Certain regular expressions require exponential amounts of memory to evaluate.  Since Firefox does this on the stack, which is limited to 10 MB on many Linux distributions, and even smaller in Windows (at least some versions of Firefox), you could hit the limit fairly quickly if you use a regular expression that requires exponential memory to convert to DFA form to evaluate.

Answer (score -1):

If your regular expression is simple like that, why not just have a loop that does string comparisons:

```
var input = "woot";

var tests = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "woot"];
for(i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
   if (tests[i] == input) {
      alert("match found: #" + i);
      break;
   }
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about browser limitations, and it'll likely perform much better as a result (since the regular expression version would have to parse and compile the regex, there'd be plenty of back tracking, and so on).

Comment: True, but it does not answer the question.